# VS2010 solution with MSTests unit tests and TFS2008 and MsBuild - fails to run unit test

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, mstest

I have a build setup on my TFS server (TFS2008) and it properly builds my VS2010 solution. (I did have to change the ToolsVersion to 4.0)

My problem is when I try to include the build definition to run my MsTests based unit tests. The build fails with the following message in the BuildLog.txt files.

**MSBUILD : warning : Visual Studio Team System for Software Testers or Visual Studio Team System for Software Developers is required to run tests as part of a Team Build.**

I have installed Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate on this machine (the build server), but that hasnt changed anything and I am still getting the above error.

What is my build machine missing?

Configuration:
TFS Server: TFS 2008
Build server: Separate machine (Has Vs2008 and VS2010 ultimate installed on it).
Solutions: VS2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get past this error what I needed to do was install both Visual Studio 2008 Developer edition and VS2010 Ultimate on the build machine.

(you may be able to get away with VS2010 Premium).

More info: http://blog.aggregatedintelligence.com/2011/03/vs2010-tfs-2008-and-unit-tests.html

But now Mstest is failing with error code 1.

Comment: Did you read my link, I had other things that I needed to do before I could get it working.

Comment: I had done all the other things but I am still getting the error

Comment: @nabeelfarid... sorry this is one of those things that you will have to just keep trying different things to try and get it working. Wish MS had setup a way for MsTest to be more verbose about its error instead of just outputting an error value of 1. The one thing i would do is to take a look at the log file and make sure all the inputs to MStest.exe are valid

Comment: Also, try restart the build server.... (and if thats not possible at least try restarting the build service).